# dbo.DTA_* tables in MSDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-blitz

I ran Brent Ozar's sp_blitz on one of my production server.  IT tagged a few tables in the MSDB database as being user created.  They all follow the pattern dbo.DTA_*.  Do these table come with MSDB, or were they added by something/someone?

Comment: Those are database tuning advisor tables that haven't been cleaned up. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899634

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are likely left over from Microsoft's Database Tuning Advisor. You should be able to get information about the sessions with this stored procedure:

```
EXEC sp_DTA_help_session
```

After identifying the sessions that you do not need you can remove them with this stored procedure supplying the session id using one as an example:

```
EXEC sp_DTA_delete_session 1
```

Comment: Correct. I flag them in sp_Blitz because they're not included in msdb by default.

Comment: Or use the following script: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/899634/description-of-the-database-tuning-advisor-dta-cleanup-script-for-sql